# Getting numericUpDown changed value inside numericUpDown changed event

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to get `nbox_qty.Text` inside it's `ValueChanged` event. The problem is, code inside event listener executed before the value of `numericUpDown` has changed.

```
Private Sub nbox_qty_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
nbox_qty.ValueChanged
    tbox_price.Text = SelectedMenuPrice * nbox_qty.Text
End Sub
```

I wanted to get `nbox_qty.Text` changed value inside the event listener. Do you have any idea to make it posible? or its definely imposible?

Comment: Is this WinForms?

Comment: Yes, I create Windows Forms with Visual Studio

Comment: The WinForms `TextBox` control doesn't have a `ValueChanged` event, so that code doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should not be using the `Text` property of a `NumericUpDown`.  It's the `ValueChanged` event because the `Value` property has changed.  It's the `Value` property you should be using because it is the number.  The `Text` is just a `String` representation of that number for display and that may not change until the UI is updated and that may not happen until all `ValueChanged` handlers have been executed.

Comment: I have just tested that theory and it is indeed the case.  If you put this code into the `ValueChanged` event handler you'll see that the `Text` hasn't changed yet but the `Value` has: `MessageBox.Show($"Value = {nbox_qty.Text
.Value}; Text = {nbox_qty.Text
.Text}")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **not** be using the `Text` property of a `NumericUpDown`. It's the `ValueChanged` event because the `Value` property has changed. It's the `Value` property you should be using because it is the number. The `Text` is just a `String` representation of that number for display and that does not change until the UI is updated and that does not happen until all `ValueChanged` handlers have been executed.

Comment: Thanks, but now Im getting confuse about updating `tbox_price.Text` just after `nbox_qty.Value` changed. Any ideas ?

Comment: What's to be confused about? Use the `Value` property of the `NumericUpDown`, not the `Text` property.  That says nothing about what to do with the value you get so that's completely up to you.  If you want to multiply that number by another number then go ahead.  If you want to display the result of that in a `TextBox` then go ahead.  To display something ina `Textbox` you set it's `Text` property.  That has absolutely nothing to do with the `NumericUpDown`.